# If ul has has no children, how can I hide or addClass to a span above it?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

So I have a jquery style accordion, with the jquery ui referenced on the page. I am pulling navigation information from a database, and the html structure looks like this:

```
<div id="accordion" class="ui-accordion ui-widget ui-helper-reset" role="tablist">
    <li class="sub-item">
        <div class="ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-accordion-icons"
            role="tab" id="ui-accordion-accordion-header-0" aria-controls="lvl2" aria-selected="false"
            tabindex="0">
            <span class="ui-accordion-header-icon ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e"></span><a href="/Ebusiness/events/upcoming-events">
                Upcoming Events</a><span id="arrow"></span></div>
        <ul id="lvl2" class="ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom"
            style="display: none;" aria-labelledby="ui-accordion-accordion-header-0" role="tabpanel"
            aria-expanded="false" aria-hidden="true">
            <li class="lvl2"><a href="/upcoming-events/meeting-center">Meeting Center</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="sub-item">
        <div class="ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-accordion-icons"
            role="tab" id="ui-accordion-accordion-header-1" aria-controls="lvl2" aria-selected="false"
            tabindex="-1">
            <span class="ui-accordion-header-icon ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e"></span><a href="/Ebusiness/Meetings/MeetingsCalendar">
                Calendar of Events</a><span id="arrow"></span></div>
        <ul id="lvl2" class="ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom"
            style="display: none;" aria-labelledby="ui-accordion-accordion-header-1" role="tabpanel"
            aria-expanded="false" aria-hidden="true">
        </ul>
    </li>
</div>
```

My goal here, is to remove the  tag, or add a class that I can then apply dispaly:none to, if there are no children in the ul#lvl2 list.

This is the jquery function I am trying, but does not seem to execute

```
if ( $('#lvl2:hasChildren') ) {
$("#arrow").addClass("empty"); }
```

I am throwing no errors.

Thanks

Comment: You should comment your own thread with code. Edit it instead. (4 spaces before a line makes it preview as code.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ( $('#lvl2').children().length )
    $("#arrow").addClass("empty");
```

or with braches:

```
if ( $('#lvl2').children().length ) {
    $("#arrow").addClass("empty");
}
```

The reason why this works is that if length is `1..Infinity` it validates as truly:

```
if ( 1 ) {
    alert("truly");
}
```

But `0` validates falsy:

```
if ( 0 ) {
    alert("falsy");
}
else {
    alert("truly");
}
```

You can push you validation to the opposite by using the `!`.

```
!0 === true;
!1 === false;
!false === true;
!true === false;
```

And again:

```
!!0 === false;
!!1 === true;
!!false === false;
!!true === true;
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work for me. I originally was trying something like this: 
if ($('ul#lvl2').children().length < 1) {
    ("span#arrow").css("display", "none");
}

Any other ideas?

Comment: It actually worked, I just had to place the function after the control. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @user2213048 you know you can accept an answer by pressing the tick.

Comment: Very cool. Thank you. Any ideas on how to do the opposite? if nochildren. or if children > 1 addClass...

Comment: Simply `if ( !$('#lvl2').children().length )`.

Comment: Very cool. I have found that my biggest issues have come from where I have been placing my functions. I was putting them too early in the DOM. However, I have run into another issue. The function is only executing on the first instance of the ul#lvl2, so that the other items in the nav are not getting the same classes added. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you are pulling the navigation information from a database and building the HTML for the navigation, I would be tempted to modify the HTML that you build and add/remove the class that way rather than use Javascript to modify the page afterwards.

If the above is not an option then I would also recommend using the .children().length() method suggested by @NULL.

Comment: It is using a .NET repeater control to fill in the html. I dont have control over individual <li> class names.

Comment: @g7876413 I wouldn't sugest using server-site to render create the html. I would more likely use ajax and create the DOM using JavaScript.

Comment: @NULL, interesting, I agree constructing the HTML from the server side is not really a good practice to get into, however if the class names are variable like above then how about binding the class property in the HTML to a property that is set by the server? I find this method useful when controlling navigation elements because I always end up with a "left" and a "right" class to determine which way the hovering div (for the children) will expand.

I also recently got caught out using javascript too heavily as it can be forced off by security settings..